# SQL query how to get the last working day of week/year in Oracle/Hive?

Tags: sql, oracle, hive, group-by, dayofweek

Supposed I have some sample data in `test_data` as below, each week has 1-5 days with data in the database(>=1 days 'There is data' <= 5 days):

```
    code     vol    val      num     test_date
   --------------------------------------------
1   00001    100    0.1      111      20191104
2   00001    100    0.1      111      20191105
3   00001    100    0.1      111      20191106
4   00001    100    0.1      111      20191107
5   00001    100    0.1      111      20191108
7   00001    100    0.1      111      20191111
8   00001    200    0.1      222      20191112
9   00001    200    0.1      111      20191113
10  00001    400    0.3      222      20191114
11  00001    200    0.2      333      20191118
12  00002    100    0.1      111      20191104
13  00002    200    0.1      222      20191105
14  00002    200    0.1      111      20191106
15  00002    400    0.3      222      20191107
16  00002    200    0.2      333      20191108
....................
....................
```

I would like to summarize `volume`, `number` and `value` by week/year and `code`, now I am able to summarize them by below SQL query, but I can't get the last date of a week according to `test_date`, the last day may be any day of a week or a year because of business/working day, we need to display that last date column

```
SELECT t.code
        ,date_add(concat_ws('-',substr(t.test_date,1,4),substr(t.test_date,5,2),substr(t.test_date,7,2)) ,
            -pmod(datediff(concat_ws('-',substr(t.test_date,1,4),substr(t.test_date,5,2),substr(t.test_date,7,2)),'1990-01-01'),7)) AS test_date
        ,sum(t.number) AS num
        ,sum(t.volume) AS vol
        ,sum(t.value) AS val
FROM test_data t
GROUP BY t.code, test_date
```

Now my output is as below:

```
    code     vol    val      num     test_date(monday)
   ----------------------------------------------------
1   00001    500    0.5      555      20191104
2   00001    900    0.6      666      20191111
3   00001    200    0.1      111      20191118
4   00001    400    0.3      222      20191125
5   00001    200    0.2      333      20191202
```

But my expected output is as below:

```
    code     vol    val      num     test_date(the last date of week in database)
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   00001    500    0.5      555      20191108
2   00001    900    0.6      666      20191114
3   00001    200    0.1      111      20191122
4   00001    400    0.3      222      20191129
5   00001    200    0.2      333      20191206
```

Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: What day is "last day of the week"? Do you mean Friday? You have tagged this question `[oracle]` as well as `[hive]` and `[impala]`: do you want a solution which works on Oracle RDBMS as well as or as an alternative to those other platform/language?

Comment: @APC The last day may be any day of a week because of business/working way. I wanna a Hive solution, I thought it was better to let you know our base database is Oracle

Comment: It is better to make your question as **clear** as possible. Different databases have different capabilities and syntax. This is especially true for date wrangling, as there is no ANSI standard. So please edit your question to clarify your requirement.

Comment: @APC I do know 'Different databases have different capabilities and syntax', that's the reason why I said our database is `Oracle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following is what you want:

```sql
SELECT t.code
     , max(t.test_date) AS test_date
     , sum(t.number) AS num
     , sum(t.volume) AS vol
     , sum(t.value)  AS val
FROM test_data t
GROUP BY t.code, TRUNC(TO_DATE(t.test_date,'RRRRMMDD'),'IW')
```

I just shortend your equation to calculate the first day of the week a bit using `TO_DATE` and `TRUNC`. Then you just select the maximum of the `test_date` for each group which is the last day in this week, where data exist.

If you just want the last of the week regardless if there is data just add the according number of days to the starting day, e.g. `TRUNC(TO_DATE(t.test_date,'RRRRMMDD'),'IW') + 6` for sunday.